# Studio Express connect failed (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got this error

> A network-related or instace-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to sql server . the server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>
> verify thai the instance name is
>   correct and that sql server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections.
>
> (privider: Named Pipes
>   Provider,error:40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL server)

My resource are
  - visual studio 2010 express version
  - studio management express

Last time I install vs2010 ex and I develop some application but I need to some data in database I downloaded studio management and installed on my pc

And I got some error "connect failed" I find any solution to solve it but not work

please help , Thank you

capture error photo files
http://i621.photobucket.com/albums/tt294/thikon/error-pipes.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were incompatible versions.

If you use

- VS 2010 Express
- MSSQL 2008 Express

You have to download [Management Studio 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b)

(I first downloaded from Management Studio 2005, which is not compatible with that version.)

Answer (score 1):

Your image shows "Cannot connect to (local)". You should connect to (local)\SQLEXPRESS instead of (local)

Also make sure (in SQL ServerConfiguration) Manager that Shared memory protocol is enabled and have **Order 1** both in SQL Server Network Configuration and and in Client Protocols.

Update
Your 2nd scan, th one  from comment, shows the error explicitly explaining that it is SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 but yous should have used 2008

Comment: Thank you for commented but i tried to user "(local)\SQLEXPRESS" 

it didn't work please see in link file 

http://www.mediafire.com/i/?jbdtcivach6str0

and in Shared memory protocal i set enabled .

Answer (score 0):

Start->Programs->SQL Server 2008 (or SQL Server 2008 R2)->Configuration Tools->`SQL Server Configuration Manager`

on Left Pane - Click on `SQL Server Services`. Check whether `SQL Server` on the Right Pane is 'Running'

on Left Pane - Click on `SQL Server Network Configuration` and expand it. You should find `Protocols for SQLEXPRESS` - click on that.
On the Right Pane, right click TCP/IP and click 'Enable'.

Tweak around a little bit - you should get it

Comment: i set enable 

  - shared Memory  -> Enabled  and 
  - Name Piped  --> Enabled and 
  - TCP/IP      -> Enabled and 
  - via   -> disable 

but didn't work .

Comment: ok - what about SQL Server Browser ( In SQL Server Services ) - is it running?

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps to be followed for enabling network client with ease.

Do these of following

Windows 7 64bit.
Sql server 2008 R2
SQL server mangement studio 2008

First install Sql server 2008 r2
Restart PC
Install SQL Server management studio 2008 as seprate instance.

For network Configuration

1-Turn Off Windows Firewall
2- Make sure That the Browser service is running and set to automatic.
3- in sqlserver confuguration manager go to sqlservernetworkconfiguration > Protocls for network

Enable TCP/IP.

You are done. :)

+